# Homotopic, winding number and continuity, Conway text

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about this.

Here is the def of homotopy used by Conway, in case you guys need it. [image]

Let $G$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\gamma$ be a closed smooth rectifiable curve in $G$ such that $\gamma$ is homotopic to a constant curve,$\gamma_o$ ;   furthermore let $ \Gamma(s,t): [0,1]\times[0,1] \to G $ be the function that satisfies the homotopic condition of $\gamma$ and $\gamma_o$.

Define $h(t) = n(\gamma_t;w) $ where $ \gamma_t(s) = \Gamma(s,t) $ for $ 0 \leq s,t \leq 1$ and $w$ is a fixed point in $ \mathbb{C}-G $. (Note: $n(\gamma;w)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ around $w$.)

Show that $h(t)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ (Assume that $\gamma_t(s)$ is smooth rectifiable for each $t$. )

I kinda have an idea of how to show this, so I'm just gonna write it out roughly and if it's correct, then I will write a more rigorous proof.

First of all, I can show that since $\Gamma$ is continuous and satisfies the homotopic condition, then for any $ \epsilon > 0$, there exist a $\delta >0$ such that $ |t-t_o|<\delta$ implies for all $ 0 \leq s \leq 1 $ $ |\Gamma(s,t)-\Gamma(s,t_o)| < \epsilon $.

Now to show continuity of $h(t)$ at $ T$, I need to bound

$$|h(t)-h(T)| = { 1 \over 2\pi}\bigg|\int_{\gamma_t}{1 \over z-w}dz- \int_{\gamma_T} {1 \over z-w} dz \bigg|$$

Let $P =\{0=p_0,p_1,...,p_n=1\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$, then
$$ |h(t)-h(T)| \leq {1 \over 2\pi} \bigg|\int_{\gamma_t}{1 \over z-w}dz- \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over \gamma_t(t^*)-w}(\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1}) \bigg|$$
$$ + {1 \over 2\pi}\bigg| \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over \gamma_t(t^*)-w}(\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1})-\int_{\gamma_T} {1 \over z-w} dz  \bigg|$$

Now by the definition of integral, I can bound the first term on the right of the inequality sign by increasing the partition of P. The only thing I need to bound now is the second term.

$$\bigg| \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over \gamma_t(t^*)-w}(\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1})-\int_{\gamma_T} {1 \over z-w} dz  \bigg| $$
$$ \leq \bigg| \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over \gamma_t(t^*)-w}(\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1}) - \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over \gamma_T(t^*)-w}(\gamma_T(p_k)-\gamma_T(p_{k-1}) \bigg| $$
$$ + \bigg| \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over \gamma_T(t^*)-w}(\gamma_T(p_k)-\gamma_T(p_{k-1}) - \int_{\gamma_T} {1 \over z-w} dz  \bigg| $$

Again, by definition of the integral, I can bound the second term on the right side of the inequality by increasing the partition of P.

I need to bound the term
$$\bigg| \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over \gamma_t(t^*)-w}(\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1}) - \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over \gamma_T(t^*)-w}(\gamma_T(p_k)-\gamma_T(p_{k-1}) \bigg| $$
to complete the proof.
The term above is less than or equal to
$$   \sum_{k=1}^n \bigg| {1 \over \gamma_t(t^*)-w}(\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1})-  {1 \over \gamma_T(t^*)-w}(\gamma_T(p_k)-\gamma_T(p_{k-1}) \bigg| $$
Adding and subtracting $$ \frac{ \gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1}) }{\gamma_T(t^*)-w} $$ inside the absolute value sign along with combining the fraction together and using the triangle inequality yield

$$ \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \bigg| \frac{\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1}) }{(\gamma_t(t^*)-w)(\gamma_T(t^*)-w) } \bigg| |\gamma_T(t^*)-\gamma_t(t^*) | $$

$$+ \sum_{k=1}^n \bigg| \frac{\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_T(p_k)}{\gamma_T(t^*)-w} \bigg| +  \sum_{k=1}^n \bigg| \frac{\gamma_t(p_{k-1})-\gamma_T(p_{k-1})}{\gamma_T(t^*)-w} \bigg| $$
In the first summand, since $\gamma_t$ is rectifiable,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n |\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1})| \leq M , M \in \mathbb{R} $$
Also, since $ w \in \mathbb{C}-G $, $$ \bigg|{ 1 \over (\gamma_t(t^*)-w)(\gamma_T(t^*)-w) } \bigg| \leq M' $$
Thus the first summand is less than or equal to
$$  \sum_{k=1}^n M' |\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1})| | \gamma_T(t^*)-\gamma_t(t^*) | $$

As I claim in the beginning, I can always control $ |t-T| $ so that for all $ 0 \leq s \leq 1$, $$ |\gamma_t(s)-\gamma_T(s) | < \epsilon $$
With this result , this mean I can control the first summand.  Similarly for the second and third summand.  Thus using partition and control the size of $ |t-T| $ , I can bound $ |h(t)-h(T)| $ which prove continuity.

Comment: I think this is too long and I couldn't see the question.

Comment: I know man, but the question is showing h(t) is continuous on [0,1]